# Не получается использовать table

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Есть база данных sql, в ней есть две таблицы, при вводе команды use user, выводится фраза Database changed. Однако при выполнении такой же последовательности но с другой таблицей use customers, появляется ошибка и пишет что такой таблицы не существует. Как такое может быть?

Comment: use используется для смены базы данных. база данных - грубо говоря папка, в которой может содержаться несколько таблиц. для работы с таблицами используются другие команды (select/insert/update/и тд)

Comment: *появляется ошибка и пишет что такой таблицы не существует* Прочитайте ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО сообщение об ошибке. Прямо по буквам...

Comment: Вам следует приложить сообщение об ошибке в вопрос